# Python Regular expression to find latest file in directory

Tags: python

I have one directory which contains below files for example purpose.

```
Directory:
ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-25.csv
AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-26_done.csv 
ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-27.csv
AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-28_done.csv 
AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv
file1
file2
fileN
```

Here how can i retrieve file which starts with ""AM_INMAG_Export_" and it should have latest timestamp using **Python**.
for example: "AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv" is the file I want to retrieve.
**BUT "fileN" is the latest modified file in the directory.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the files that match your desired prefix and then sort.

```
>>> files = """ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-25.csv
... AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-26_done.csv
... ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-27.csv
... AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-28_done.csv
... AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv
... file1
... file2
... fileN""".split('\n')
>>> files
['ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-25.csv', 'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-26_done.csv ', 'ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-27.csv', 'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-28_done.csv ', 'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv', 'file1', 'file2', 'fileN']
>>> filtered_files = [ x for x in files if x.startswith('AM_INMAG_Export_')]
>>> sorted_files = sorted(filtered_files,reverse=True)
>>> sorted_files[0]
'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv'
```

---

**Update**

Filter filenames with a regexp and then sort.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> files = [
...   'ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-25.csv',
...   'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-26_done.csv',
...   'ERROR_AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-27.csv',
...   'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-28_done.csv',
...   'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-21.csv',
...   'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-25.csv',
...   'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv',
...   'file1',
...   'file2',
...   'fileN'
... ]
>>>
>>> file_re = re.compile(r'^AM_INMAG_Export_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.csv$')
>>> filtered_files = [ x for x in files if file_re.match(x)]
>>> sorted_files = sorted(filtered_files,reverse=True)
>>> sorted_files[0]
'AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv'
```

Comment: if "AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-29.csv" file not present it should not give "AM_INMAG_Export_2016-07-28_done.csv"

Comment: @ThejeshPR: your original question does not make this distinction; you just say `retrieve file which starts with ""AM_INMAG_Export_"`

Comment: Yes, You are right, it can be done by using x.startswith('AM_INMAG_Export_') and not x.endswith('_done.csv').

Answer (score 1):

```
files = glob.glob('AM_INMAG_Export_*.csv')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[3].split('.')[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob)

```
import glob
print( glob.glob('AM_INMAG_Export_????-??-??.csv')[-1] )
```

This will work if the time defined in the name is actually the updated time. Otherwise , you should use [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.stat) to find

```
import glob
import os

def find_last_updated(pattern):
    def find_updated(ff):
        return os.stat(ff).st_mtime

    last = None 
    last_updated = 0
    for ff in glob.glob(pattern):
        ff_updated = find_updated(ff)
        if last == None or ff_updated > last_updated :
            last = ff
            last_updated = ff_updated
    return last

print(find_last_updated('AM_INMAG_Export-????-??-??.csv'))
```

Comment: He explicitly says the latest file should be derived from the file name and not from the time the files were modified.

Comment: Well, He did not say it **explicitly** :-) From the example he gave , you can conclude both cases.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you need to use regex to get the date as a group item. Once you have all of the groups you need to convert that to a python date and then check to see which one has the greatest date.

```
import re
pat = re.compile("^AM_INMAG_Export_(.+)\.csv$")
matches = pat.match(your_data)
```

This is the regular expression you will be looking to use, you could go into more detail around the grouping and get an actual date format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use `glob` to get the files and then sort the file names from the earliest to the oldest file:

```
files = glob.glob('<YOUR_DIRECTORY>/AM_INMAG_Export_*') # the file prefix + '*' as regex
files.sort(reverse=True) # sort and use 'reverse=True' to get a list of files sorted by the earliest to the oldest
your_precious_file = files[0] # the one with the oldest date
```

**Note:** the assumption here is that all files have identical prefix and post-fix, and the difference is due to the date.

Answer (score 0):

A list of files obtained with glob.glob() can be sorted with the sorted statement. See the following example

```
import os
import glob


def main():
    """
    Sort csv Files.
    """
    for f in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join('AM_INMAG_Export_*.csv')), reverse=True):
        print("File " + f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```